# Unable to resolve mailer and util plugin [2.2 java ]

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I am new to play 2.2 framework. I am getting started with secure social plugin and I have unresolved dependencies during compilation.

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-util_2.10;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#play-plugins-mailer_2.10;2.2.0: not found
```

The content of my build.sbt is:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
   "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.1",
   "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.1",
   "securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)


resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",
    new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("typesafe plugins", new URL("http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-snapshots", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

and play.plugins is

```
1000:org.jooq.play.JooqPlugin
150000:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
9994:securesocial.core.DefaultAuthenticatorStore
9995:securesocial.core.DefaultIdGenerator
9996:securesocial.core.providers.utils.DefaultPasswordValidator
9997:securesocial.controllers.DefaultTemplatesPlugin
9998:your.user.Service.Implementation <-- Important: You need to change this
9999:securesocial.core.providers.utils.BCryptPasswordHasher
10004:securesocial.core.providers.UsernamePasswordProvider
```

I have also tried to download these jars and put them in lib folder. Is this a known issue? It would be great if someone can help me out on this. Also, like in rails, how do we force installing the plugins to a given path like bundle `install --path=.path` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `build.sbt` should work:

```
name := """hello-play"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-snapshots", new URL("http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-snapshots/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.2.0",
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.2.0",
  "securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```